# Design View is not opening in Blend 2013

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, blend

I saw set of people have the same problem and I tried some it, But I do not know why I still cannot see the design view!!

1. The output type is Windows Application.
2. Design view is working properly in VS 2013.
3. I created this project using MVVM Light Templates; So I do not know if there is a missing stuff in project file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem until few minutes ago.
I've noticed that Blend 2013 on my PC was supporting up to .NET Framework 4.5.1

But the project on Visual Studio was done with .NET Framework 4.6.1

I changed the Framework to 4.5.1, since that was the latest Blend supports, and that was it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to
Tools>Options>Documents and in default document view option select which view you liked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, It was split view already. I believe this is not the reason.

Comment: you can try above option to change XAML not HTML

Comment: I've tried this, but like @bunjeeb, I still have the same issue.